# Open a button on pageload

Tags: button, pageload

How do I get a 'button' clicked automatically on pageload with a script?
And how can I add a randomness factor to the script?

This is the button. When it's clicked it shows a pop up window.

```html
<button class="lightbox-btn">
  <span>Iscriviti alla newsletter</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your first question -

If you are using jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox-btn').click();
});
```

If your are not using jQuery-

```
 window.onload = function(){
         document.getElementsByClassName('lightbox-btn').click();
    }
```

What do u mean by factor of randomness ??

Math.random(); gives a random number in javascript.